# C++ return double pointer from function.... what's wrong?

Tags: c++, pointers, function, function-pointers

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my function.... I need to ask the user for a price and then return it as a double pointer, but I get tons and tons of errors:

```
double* getPrice()

{

    double* price;

    cout << "Enter Price of CD: " << endl;

    cin >> &price;



    return price;

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to use a pointer of any kind it needs to point to valid memory.  Right now you have a pointer which is uninitialized and points to garbage.  Try the following

```
double* price = new double();
```

Additionally you need to have cin pass to a `double` not a `double**`.

```
cin >> *price;
```

Note this will allocate new memory in your process which must be freed at a later time.  Namely by the caller of getPrice.  For example

```
double* p = getPrice();
...
delete p;
```

Ideally in this scenario you shouldn't be allocated a pointer at all because it introduces unnecessary memory management overhead.  A much easier implementation would be the following

```
double getPrice() {
  double price;
  cout << "Enter Price of CD: " << endl;
  cin >> price;
  return price;
}
```